# Requesting specific detailed answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-suggestions, similar-questions

Is it unreasonable to ask for very specific detailed answers?

Many times when I post a question I'll get multiple answers that are close to but not exactly what I'm asking. Over time I started to state specifically that I have very specific requirements and that the answer I'm looking for has to meet these requirements.

Even after stating that I still get the same the responses. That is annoying but I can deal with. I can ignore or down vote those answers. But what seems to happen is that there are moderators who do the same thing. They find a similar question and then mark my question as a duplicate ignoring requirements.

Even when I've stated I've seen similar questions or even when I've linked to the question in my post they have marked it as a duplicate.

I have previous questions I can link to but I don't want this to be about the questions I want to discuss if it's unreasonable to ask for specific answers.

Reddit has a serious tag that someone can use if they want only serious answers.

[image]

It's been a member for about 6 years. I thought this would change but it hasn't. Please add this feature.

Comment: _"Many times when I post a question I'll get multiple answers that are close to but not exactly what I'm asking."_ TL;DR; Put a clear and answerable question in 1st place! And no reddit feature requests here please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm very specific in my questions. Who says not to asks for features here? I asked for a feature that is similar to what Reddit has as a way to handle this case. I've also marked this as a discussion on ways to fix this issue. It against your principles to upgrade software and make it better?

Comment: It's already implicit that you want specific answers, so if you *consistently* 
aren't getting them, either a) your questions aren't as clear or specific as you think, b) you aren't understanding the answers [often an answerer may spot a bigger picture than you do, especially if you've been hyperfocused on a problem for a while], or c) there's always the possibility that the site you're referring to is e.g. a beta site that's on its way out without a good user base any more. But a and b are the most likely on all of the established sites.

Comment: @JasonC I already do that. There are questions that have multiple solutions or easy answers and then there are my cases where I need a specific answer to achieve a specific goal. Usually to do with performance or other constraints. So in those questions I state my requirements. However it doesn't matter. What if, maybe it's not my fault. Maybe it's people have a good nature and want to help answer questions and specifics seem irrelevant and so they answer anyway?

Comment: I like that people downvote a discussion and asking for feedback on making the site or my posts better.

Answer (score 7):

I think it comes down to *writing a good question to start with*. And well, we aren't Reddit. I've found a few things *usually help*.

*Show awareness of current posts and where they fall short*.

"I've tried this answer here, and I'm not happy with the frobulator throttle being stuck on full throttled scaring my wildebeest. I would like to thomp my frobulator with the ability to control the throttle"

So it shows you've read through the answer, mentioned a problem with it and why it's a practical issue.

*Saying* you want a detailed answer isn't enough - *detailed*, well written questions

Also, we aren't Reddit. [We hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). All questions and answers, really need to be as serious as the fox below.

[image]

And while I think it's probably a sidetrack, I suspect some of what you say in your profile is worth addressing in this context

> Almost all of my questions use fictional scenarios because 90% of the time my questions have much different requirements than normal.

As per the [help] pages on many sites

> ou should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

as well as

> Sometimes I'll post a question and someone marks the question "didn't
>   research. found on Google". No, I did research but the answer was
>   insufficient, I couldn't find what you found or the answer didn't
>   exist on SE

Excellent. This can be in your questions, which makes it a *lot* harder for people to say it didn't.

So... It's up to you to *show* us your posts aren't duplicates.

Comment: Imagine if you will, that this has happened in about 1 in 3 questions you've posted. Now, here's my most recent question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770246/can-php-curl-return-an-object-with-body-and-headers-in-a-single-request. If rewording my question will help I'll reword every question in the future. If it doesn't help can we discuss other solutions?

Comment: I don't read PHP, so I can't really give concrete suggestions on that.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for an actual answer. I'm asking for your feedback. If there is anything you would change in my original question to let the reader know that I need a specific answer. I've mentioned over the last two paragraphs what I need and what type of answers are not helpful to me. Even after writing my requirements I still get moderators closing my questions or providing an answering that disregards my requirements.

Comment: If this was SU or another site I'm familiar with I'd be glad to. SO isn't really my cup of tea. I'd dump the last para for certain. Link the question you refer to and *show* why its different and maybe your current output. Its also worth remembering that's not a mod, its a user with a gold badge in that tag

Comment: What if there's a moderator or a user with a gold badge that doesn't realize that a question is not a duplicate? I mean hypothetically speaking. I know it's probably rare and I'm sure it never happens but what if there was a one exceptional gold user or moderator who marked questions as duplicates that were not duplicates?

Comment: That's practically a whole different question, and in theory the community should end up handling that.

Comment: What is the species (Canidae)?

Comment: Vulpes ferrilata - The Tibetan sand fox. Quite well known for being serious looking critters

Answer (score 6):

I know you did not want to focus on a specific example, but really that's what's necessary here because your general question ...

> I want to discuss if it's unreasonable to ask for specific [answers].

... is, quite frankly, silly. Of course it's reasonable to ask for specific answers. You can ask for whatever you want. The end.

---

Now that your general question is taken care of, I'm assuming [Can PHP curl return an object with body and headers in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43770246) is what triggered you to ask this, as it's your only recent question and it fits the bill of the effect you describe. My intent is to critique that specific question, but only as a good example for what *you* can do in general to get the answers you want.

Basically, it's already pretty much implicit that an asker wants a specific answer. If you consistently aren't getting them, then it's usually one of the following:

- Your questions aren't as clear or specific as you think,
- You aren't understanding the answers (often an answerer may spot a bigger picture than you do, especially if you've been hyperfocused on a problem for a while), or
- There's always the possibility that the site you're referring to is e.g. a beta site that's on its way out without a good user base any more. But on all of the established sites, the previous two are far more likely.

It should be telling that the overwhelming responses you're getting here are "ask clearer questions": The reason we're all saying that is *it's correct*. Also you write:

> What if, maybe it's not my fault.

Maybe it's not, but, logically speaking, in general, when you observe consistent undesirable responses from others, it's far more likely that the problem is on your end rather than with everybody else around you. Also:

> Maybe it's people have a good nature and want to help answer questions and specifics seem irrelevant and so they answer anyway?

Even if that is the case, the mere fact that you *know* that's the case means you have even *less* of an "excuse" for not constructing questions to work around this. Still, this isn't the actual reason, so let's go back to that PHP curl question:

---

So back to your specific question. It has some subtle but important flaws. In your question you wrote this:

> I've seen a similar question that suggests requesting both the headers and body and then parsing the results. I'm not asking about that. I'm specifically asking about returning an `object` with the body and headers as separate properties.

That's all you wrote, and the provided answer does, in fact, give you precisely what you *appeared* to have asked for: A way to return an object with the body and headers as separate properties. It wasn't until later in a comment that you wrote:

> I appreciate the answer but my requirement is that it does not do any parsing.

But you *weren't* actually clear about that. Memor-X's response to you nailed it and you should've taken that response to heart (emphasis mine):

> i don't see that requirement, **just a passing mention that other answers do it like that but you don't want to**.

**If you have specific requirements, you need to state them clearly.**

Secondly, you wrote, in a comment:

> Hi please reopen. I already read that question my question is not a duplicate

But a reader has *no way of knowing what question you were referring to* when you wrote "I've seen a similar question". **When you have done some prior research and found an existing question, in order to assert that your question is not a duplicate of that one you have to at least link to it and give a brief mention why**, otherwise you do not get to be surprised if your question is marked as a dupe, because nobody has any way of knowing if you've read the dupe or not.

SO, your issue seems to be in your communication. In particular, **you're counting a bit too much on the ability of readers to read your mind**. That's all there is to it. Here is an example of what you *should* have written in your question:

> I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request), and all of the answers suggest requesting both the headers and body and then parsing the results. However, my requirement is that I do not do any parsing at all on my end, and so none of those answers work for me. I'm specifically looking for something that returns the header and bodies separately to me, without me having to parse them.

You can't really argue that that isn't 1000x clearer than what you wrote.

Your mistake is actually twofold: Not only are you leaving some gaps in your stated requirements, but, more importantly, *you convinced yourself that you were being absolutely clear*, and so immediately closed yourself off to the possibility of learning from the experience. When we all tell you "ask clearer questions", or when commenters say things like "I didn't see that requirement", or when you consistently get less-than-ideal responses from others, *don't ignore those valuable hints*.

So, yeah, mind reading isn't real. You *have* to be clear. If you don't adequately place constraints on the answers you receive, then you can't be surprised if you consistently get answers that don't meet your needs, or dupe closures that aren't appropriate.

In closing here's a great, relevant point from Jon Skeet's [nice little question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), which pretty much sums up your major issue:

> Have you read the whole question to yourself carefully, to make sure it makes sense and contains enough information for someone coming to it without any of the context that you already know?

Your formatting looks great, your grammar is on point, you've done almost everything right, you just need to work on providing clearer context.

Comment: Thanks. This is something I can do differently in the future.

Answer (score 4):

> Reddit has a [serious](/questions/tagged/serious) tag that someone can use if they want only serious answers.

**What a silly feature is that??**

So without applying that tag you are left open for non serious (joke) answers and all kind of unrelated stuff?

Stack Exchange has quality policies for every site in 1st place.

Answers that won't match these will be downvoted or deleted at all.

Same applies for non-serious or otherwise *off-topic* questions.

---

> I want to discuss if it's unreasonable to ask for specific questions.

Depends, if your topic is too (specific) localized to be useful for a broader audience in a community, it may be closed as too broad (sounds contradictory I know).

---

> Even when I've stated I've seen similar questions or even when I've linked to the question in my post they have marked it as a duplicate.

Make it crystal clear in your question why these *"duplicates"* answers aren't applicable for your specific problem.

Comment: Well, if it worked I wouldn't be here asking to discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to request specific detailed answers: Ask specific detailed questions.

Try to see if someone else has asked the same question before.
Explain how your question is different from some earlier questions.
If you want details on some specific point, do mention what the point is.

If you want details on all possible things, I suggest asking a series of more focused questions instead.
But if you do so and the questions are related, please provide links between the questions for context, explain how the questions differ, and wait for answers and feedback from one question before asking the next one.

You didn't provide any links to example questions, so I can only answer at a general level.

I've used SE sites for years, and formulating a good question which clearly communicates my goal to others is still challenging.
I still make mistakes with it.
Explaining what you want to know exactly can take quite a lot of effort.
One method I find helpful is trying to purposely misunderstand my own question; if I fail, others have a better chance of reading the question I had in mind.